# Наложение условий на внешние ключи в MySQl

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый вечер, уважаемые пользователи. Меня интересует такой вопрос.

Пусть есть три таблици. phones с полями id, model_id; models: id, name; features: id, model_id. `phones.model_id = models.id`, `features.model_id = models.id`. Где писать ограничения на models.id в обоих таблицах phones и features или только в одно?
И если я напишу  в phones `ON DELETE CASCADE`, в features `ON DELETE RESTRICT`, какое из уловий примениться к полю models.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой из модификаторов `RESTRICT`/`CASCADE`/`SET NULL` устанавливать - зависит от Вашей бизнес-логики. Если в списке внешних ключей сработало `RESTRICT` ограничение, то отменяется вся операция обновления/удаления и БД возвращается в то же состояние, какое было до начала операции. Клиенту, при этом, выдается сообщение об ошибке о невозможности выполнить операцию из-за наличия дочерних записей

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли, сейчас

Comment: @up-and-coming В чем же я Вас неправильно понял?

Comment: вот на конкретном примере, если ссідки имеются в разніх таблицах на одно и тоже поле. Где писать єти ограничия,в обоих ли дочерних таблицах. И відаст ли ошибку в случае противоречивіх ограничений на поле?

Comment: @up-and-coming Еще раз: ограничение указывается при создании **каждого** внешнего ключа. Какое именно ограничение указывать - зависит от Вашей бизнес-логики. Если Вы не указали ограничение, то MySQL подставит `RESTRICT`. При проектировании БД Вы можете указывать любые комбинации. Что произойдет при обновлении/удалении я уже написал

Comment: я имею в виду, ссыдка на ключ есть в разных А НЕ В ОДНОЙ ТАБЛИЦАХ. В одной есть ссылка на поле из третей таблица и на это же поле третей таблици есть ссылка из второй таьлици вот

Comment: @up-and-coming Я Вам про это и пишу. Перечитайте вдумчиво мой ответ

Comment: все понял спасибо